# How to build a catalogue in CQ 5.6.1

Tags: java, aem, crx

I'm a newbie in CQ5. My website has a catalogue to show many items.

Ex:

1. Sports 
     1.1. Football 
               1.1.1. premier league 
               1.1.2. La Liga 
     1.2. Tennis
2. Education 
     2.1. Money 
     2.2. University

Does CQ5 has an existing component for rendering the above catalogue ? If not, how can I structure it in CQ5 ?

appreciate your help.
many thanks

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure of what you mean by a catalogue here, but it sounds like you could achieve your requirement by following an appropriate hierarchy for each of these pages

Comment: I mean it is multi-level catalogue. Ex: Sports has sub-catalogue is    Football & tennis. Which component can I use in CQ5? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that each entry in your hierarchy (1.1, 1.1.1, etc.) corresponds to a page in the CRX (i.e., a content node).  Given that, you could start with the [list component](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/default_components/editmode.html#List); the OOTB component shows only one level, but I suspect that you could customize it to retrieve and display multiple levels.